# How do I calculate the proportion of smaller squares covered by a larger circle?

Tags: r, proportion, weights, gis

I would like to determine the proportion covered by the circle (say r = 2800m) of each cell (say 1000 x 1000 m). The circle is centered around the center of the focal cell of a rectangular neighborhood. I provide a rough visual estimation in the attached picture to clarify the idea. I.e. "1" means fully included, and "0" means no overlap.

The problem occurs in spatial modeling and coordinates are in meters (epsg:6933). This rules out sampling approaches as extremely inefficient (thanks for the suggestion though!).

Ideally the solution should should be implemented easily in R.
Any suggestion would be highly welcome. Thanks.

[Yes , I know the dot is missing in two "0.09"s]

[image]

Comment: @Rainer do you want the solution for this specific sized circle with this specific grid size or do you want something more general

Comment: I want it to be more general. I found a clean solution and will post it once I am able to answer my own question. I use R packages sp, raster and rgeos.

Comment: Do you want some way of estimating for each cell the proportion that that particular circle covers (that is to say the numbers in small print in your diagram)?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have any statistical/probabilistic component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This question asks how to construct a rasterized two-dimensional kernel for a circular uniform distribution.**

The underlying mathematical problem is this: given a planar circle $R$ and a rectangle $X,$ find the area of $X\cap R$.  The kernel's values will be these areas divided by the area of $R$ (so that it integrates to unity).

This is an elementary integration problem but it's messy.  Borrowing statistical methods for describing probability distributions in two dimensions, we can construct the solution out of simpler ones.  These are:

1. **Shift and scale**.  Choose the circle's center as the origin and choose units of measurement in which it has a unit radius.
2. **Create a "distribution function."**  This function $F$ of two arguments $x$ and $y$ returns the area of the circle located to the left of $x$ and beneath $y$.  Using it we may express the area of the circle covered by the rectangle with lower left corner $(x_0,y_0)$ and upper right corner $(x_1,y_1)$ as

   $$f(x_0,y_0; x_1,y_1) = F(x_1,y_1) - F(x_0,y_1) - F(x_1,y_0) + F(x_0,y_0).$$
3. **Exploit symmetries.** By negating $x$ and or $y$ and swapping $x$ with $y$ as necessary we can relate $F(x,y)$ to the value of $F(u,v)$ where $u \ge v\ge 0$.
4. The computation requires the "marginal" distributions $F_X(x)$, the area of the circle to the left of $x$, and $F_Y(y)$, the area beneath $y$. By symmetry $F_X=F_Y$.

By integration (or elementary trigonometry) we find that for $-1 \le x \le 1$,

$$F_X(x) = \pi/2  + \arcsin(x) + x\sqrt{1-x^2}.$$

(The pieces are twice the areas of a quarter circle, a sector, and a triangle, respectively.) This function rises from $0$ to $\pi$.

I leave the details of (1) - (3) to the interested reader (they can be found in the implementation of `pucirc` below).  They can all be worked out by carving $R$ along the vertical lines at $0$ and $x$ and the horizontal lines at $0$ and $y$.  There are really only two distinct cases to consider: $(x,y)$ lies inside the circle or outside it (that is, $x^2+y^2$ is less than $1$ or greater than $1$).  All the resulting pieces can be expressed in terms of $F_X$, simple constants, and simple functions (like $xy$, which is the area of the rectangle from the origin to the point $xy$).

To illustrate, here are the overlap areas in a unit grid for a central circle of radius $2.8$, as requested in the question.

[image: Labeled raster image]

The circle's boundary is overlaid in orange.  The areas of each cell are posted (rounded to $0.001$).  They were found by applying $f$ repeatedly to each of the cells: see the "Application" section in the code for details.

As a quick check, the last line of this code sums all the cell areas and compares them to the theoretical area of the circle.  The resulting discrepancy should be zero (and it is in this example).  Several tests (which graph various functions) have been left in but commented out.

```R
#
# Area of a circle of radius `r`, centered at `origin`,
# to the left of `x` and below `y`.
#
pucirc <- function(x, y, radius=1, origin=c(0,0)) {
  #
  # Helper function.
  #
  xsqrt <- function(x) {
    y <- pmax(-1, pmin(1, x))
    y * sqrt(1 - y^2) + asin(y)
  }
  #
  # Area of the unit circle to the left of `x`.
  #
  pucirc_margin <- function(x) {
    ifelse(x >= 1, pi, ifelse(x <= -1, 0, pi/2 + xsqrt(x)))
  }
  # curve(pucirc_margin(x), from=-1.5, to=1.5)
  #
  # Area of the unit circle below `y` and to the left of `x` for
  # 0 <= x,y
  #
  pucirc_ <- function(x, y) {
    u <- pmax(x, y)
    v <- pmin(x, y)
    ifelse(u >= 1, pucirc_margin(v),
           ifelse(u^2+v^2 > 1, pucirc_margin(u) + pucirc_margin(v) - pi,
                  pucirc_margin(u)/2 + pucirc_margin(v)/2 - pi/4 + u*v))
  }
  # curve(pucirc_margin(x), from=0, to=1.5, ylim=c(0, pi), lwd=2)
  # curve(pucirc_(x, 0), add=TRUE, col="Gray", lty=3, lwd=2)
  # for (y in c(1/3, 0.9, 1)) {
  #   curve(pucirc_(x, y), from=0, to=1.5, add=TRUE, col=hsv(y * 2/3), lwd=2)
  # }
  #
  # Area of the unit circle below `y` and to the left of `x` for
  # any `x` and `y`.
  #
  pucirc0 <- function(x, y) {
    ifelse(x < 0 & y < 0, pi - pucirc_margin(-x) - pucirc_margin(-y) + pucirc_(-x, -y),
           ifelse(x < 0 & y >= 0, pucirc_margin(y) - pucirc_(-x, y),
                  ifelse(x >= 0 & y < 0, pucirc_margin(x) - pucirc_(x, -y),
                         pucirc_(x, y))))
  }
  # curve(pucirc_margin(x), from=-1.5, to=1.5, ylim=c(0, pi), lwd=2)
  # curve(pucirc0(x, 0), add=TRUE, col="Gray", lty=3, lwd=2)
  # for (y in c(-1, -1/2, 1/3, 0.9, 1)) {
  #   curve(pucirc0(x, y), add=TRUE, col=hsv((y+1) * 1/3), lwd=2)
  # }
  pucirc0((x-origin[1])/radius, (y-origin[2])/radius) * radius^2
}
#
# Area of a circle overlapping a rectangle with lower left corner `ll`
# and upper right corner `ur`.
#
pucirc_rect <- function(ll, ur, radius=1, origin=c(0,0)) {
  pucirc(ur[1], ur[2], radius, origin) - 
    pucirc(ur[1], ll[2], radius, origin) -
    pucirc(ll[1], ur[2], radius, origin) +
    pucirc(ll[1], ll[2], radius, origin)
}
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#
# Application: construct a rasterized circular uniform kernel.
#
library(data.table) # Fast calculation
library(ggplot2)    # Graphical display

radius <- 2.8
rmax <- floor(2*radius) / 2     # Smallest rectangle coordinate
rmin <- floor(-2*radius-1) / 2  # Larges rectangle coordinate
#
# Create a table of all lower-left cell coordinates.
#
X <- as.data.table(expand.grid(i=seq(rmin, rmax, by=1), j=seq(rmin, rmax, by=1)))
#
# Compute the overlap areas for the cells.
#
f <- Vectorize(function(i,j) pucirc_rect(c(i,j), c(i,j)+1, radius=radius))
invisible(X[, Overlap := f(i,j)])
#
# Create data to plot the circle itself.
#
theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=361)
P <- data.table(x=cos(theta)*radius, y=sin(theta)*radius)
#
# Plot everything.
#
g <- ggplot(X, aes(i,j)) + 
  geom_raster(aes(fill=Overlap, alpha=Overlap), hjust=1, vjust=1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=round(Overlap, 3)), nudge_x=1/2, nudge_y=1/2, size=3) + 
  geom_path(data=P, aes(x, y), size=1.5, alpha=2/3, color="Orange") + 
  guides(alpha="none", fill="none") + 
  coord_fixed(ratio=1)

print(g)
#
# Check.
#
sum(X$Overlap) / (pi * radius^2) - 1 # Should be zero.
```

Comment: Thank you for the generalization and mathematical explanation. Great job. You do get the same results as I do, though. See the edit of my answer.

Comment: Forgot to mark your answer as such! Done.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use sampling. Create a matrix of your squares. Take samples from two uniform variables, interpret those as x and y values. Keep them only if they fall in the circle. Count those towards the square in which they belong. The estimated fraction of a square in a circle is then number of samples it caught, divided by the expected number of samples (= total samples / number of squares). Not the most efficient solution, but, very easy to implement, and it will work if you take enough samples.

Comment: very straightforward and definitely solving the question, yet utterly inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

Below is R code. I hope it is reproducible for everyone.
Cell size is set in 4th block of code with "res"
The radius is set in the 2ndlast block/line with "width".
Missing: generalization to omit providing a reasonable estimate

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal) 
require(rgeos)

epsg6933 <- CRS("+init=epsg:6933")

study_extent <- extent(5836086, 14150225, -1388257, 6628905)

rasterdummy <- raster(x = study_extent, crs = epsg6933, res = c(1000, 1000))

# next comes the estimate as in the picture. could be 0s and 1s though.
focweight <- matrix(c(0,    0,    0.09, 0.25, 0.09, 0,    0, 
                      0,    0.45, 0.99, 1,    0.99, 0.45, 0,
                      0.09, 0.99, 1,    1,    1,    0.99, 0.09,
                      0.25, 1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    0.25,
                      0.09, 0.99, 1,    1,    1,    0.99, 0.09,
                      0,    0.45, 0.99, 1,    0.99, 0.45, 0,
                      0,    0,    0.09, 0.25, 0.09, 0,    0), nrow = 7)

focweight[focweight!=0] <- cellFromPolygon(object = rasterdummy, p = gBuffer(spgeom =  SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(c(study_extent@xmin + 10500, study_extent@ymax - 10500), ncol = 2), proj4string = epsg6933, bbox = bbox(rasterdummy)), quadsegs = 720, width = 2800), weights = T)[[1]][,2]

focweight # to print values to stdout
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This code doesn't determine anything: it simply outputs the result posted in your question.   Where did it come from?  How accurate is it?  How can you generalize it to other neighborhood sizes?  The answers aren't even correct to two decimal places!  (Sampling, as suggested in another answer, could give you three significant figures in less than a second.)

Comment: @whuber what you perceive as the "answers" is a visual estimate... the values differing from zero are replaced by creating a circular buffer (720 segments) around the center of the focal cell and using the in-built function of raster::cellFromPolygon to return weights. for your convenience I will include a png of the actual values as determined by my answer.

Comment: Please note that some of your values are still erroneous: for instance, $0.30$ is not a good two-digit approximation to $0.285$ nor is $0.99$ a correct two-digit representation of $0.984$.

Comment: @whuber not sure but i am working in an equal are projection which may have some latitude-dependent effect

Comment: By definition, "equal-area" means there will be no such effect.  Your circle might not be a true spherical circle, but you will have to live with that when you're working with focal statistics of raster datasets.

Comment: @whuber equal are projections are NOT perfect in their equal area property. In particular epsg:6933 is recommended only for low and mid latitude application because of this exact problem... http://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/1/1/32

Comment: By definition, an equal area projection does preserve the areas *of the spheroid.* They may be "imperfect" due to inaccuracy of the spheroid or through approximate calculations.  Those errors are typically two orders of magnitude less than those shown in the question.

Comment: @whuber It might be due to how rounding is handled in R in general and in the packages I used. For me this accuracy is sufficient. It is much better than using no weighting at all. your code is however, obviously superior.

Comment: `R` does not implicitly round: it carries out its calculations in double precision (about 16 decimal places).  For most purposes one-digit accuracy is indeed sufficient.  But if one has the opportunity to use more-accurate values, at no cost in computational time or programming effort, it seems to make little sense not to. In many applications, too, it is important that the weights add up *exactly* to the focal area (I believe yours do not) so that the focal mean or sum is unbiased. This is particularly important when repeated focal operations are applied, because that will magnify any bias.